# React JS - React Material UI icons not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react Material UI, and I received the following error.

> "Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/Lock'"

```
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Lock';
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: could you add the package.json file to see the dependencies.

Comment: In case you have installed UI icons, the import statement might need a change.. try `import {LockIcon} from 'material-ui/icons'

Answer (score 15):

```
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
```

then add font material icons to index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed `@material-ui/icons` package. You can validate it from `node_modules`

---

This would resolve your issue,

```
npm install --save @material-ui/icons
```

Answer (score 0):

MUI have since separated their `icons` from core into a separate node_module called `@material-ui/icons`.

Here's a good example on how to setup your MUI Icons with React:
https://mechanicalrock.github.io/2021/04/27/fed-talk-s01e01-getting-started#keyboard-getting-started-with-material-ui

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative is you cant install the node modules:

1. Add "" to your head tag, or whever you store your links to style sheets.
2. Add a span tag with class name "material-icons" and make the content of the span the icon you want to use. example: menu

You can find more info about all the icons [here](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons&icon.query=menu)

Answer (score 0):

This syntax worked for me in React
import VolumeUp   from '@mui/icons-material/VolumeUp'

and you must install npm i --save '@mui/icons-material'

You can find more info [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material) and a React Code Generator [here](https://www.reactevolve.com)

Answer (score 0):

Install the library

`"npm install @material-ui/icon --force"`