# Material UI svg Icon: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, webpack-dev-server

```
ERROR in ./src/components/navigator/Navigator.tsx
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/DnsRounded' in '.../src/components/navigator'
 @ ./src/components/navigator/Navigator.tsx 36:0-59 53:30-44
 @ ./src/components/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
```

Current dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.6.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
```

one of the example import I did in the Navigator.tsx is:

```js
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';

// in render method:
<HomeIcon />
```

Things I have tried to fix this issue:
1. npm i @material-ui/icons@latest (next, old 3.x.x versions, etc)
2. reinstall the dependencies.
3. add icon link to index.html.
So far none of them have worked. I keep getting the module not found error while compiling. I also checked the node_modules, I can find the **@material-ui/icons** package in there. Moreover, I can use cmd + click to navigate to the source code in my VSCode.

Again, I am trying to use the SVG Icon instead of the Font Icon.

Comment: try this:npm install @material-ui/icons and import like one of these options: Option 1:

import AccessAlarmIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccessAlarm';
import ThreeDRotation from '@material-ui/icons/ThreeDRotation';
Option 2:

import { AccessAlarm, ThreeDRotation } from '@material-ui/icons';

Comment: try : npm rebuild

Comment: @EhsanSadeghi unfortunately I have tried both of them, none of them worked. in the second option, it will compile with a warning. But at render time, I will receive Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: @JayVaghasiya I have tried that, no luck

Comment: due to this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421110/react-js-react-material-ui-icons-not-working -->   then add font material icons to index.html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React JS - React Material UI icons not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421110/react-js-react-material-ui-icons-not-working)

Comment: Do I import Icon before importing HomeIcon? Also, I have the <link> inside the index.html body.

Comment: Also, I am trying to use the SVG icons not the font icon.

Comment: update: I can use the font Icon using the method the other question states, however, it does not solve the problem of not being able to import svgicons from @marterial-ui/icons directly.